# How do I get CMake to work with QtCreator?

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

I started learning Qt, but immediately ran into an unpleasant problem: commands for building and launching the application are not available, and when I try to execute the "Run CMake" command, the message ":-1: error: CMake version is unsupported. Update to version 3.14 (with file-api) or later.". In the settings on the "CMake" tab, the CMake assembly is indicated by an exclamation mark in red, when hovering, a tooltip appears with the message "CMake executable does not provide required IDE integration features.", and "no" opposite "Supports file API". Please tell me how to fix it. CMake version 3.21.1, came with Qt, Qt Creator version 7.0.2 (Community), Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 21H2.

Thanks!

Comment: What does it say in Tools > Options on the CMake tab of "Kits"? That's where it looks for CMake executables.

Comment: This should work. Do you have an antivirus enabled? What happens if you temporary disable it.

Starting with Qt Creator 6 there is a new process starting feature enabled, which can be turned off by setting `QTC_USE_QPROCESS`  to `1` as environment variable.

Comment: Please post the command that it tries to run.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the environment variable QTC_USE_QPROCESS to 1 helped.